# grep -w is not unique if dash is in string

Tags: linux, bash, grep

iIf a dash is in the string "grep -w" is not unique. How can I solve this?

**Example:**

File1:

> football01
>  football01test

```
# grep -iw ^football01
football01
```

File2:

> football01
>  football01-test

```
# grep -iw ^football01
football01
football01-test
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific in your question? Also please mention the expected output too in code tags

Comment: The `-w` flag makes grep only match on whole words, and `-` is considered a word separator.  If you are trying to match on the whole line you could use `grep -i "^football01$"`

Comment: @Michael, if one of the answers helped you, can you please mark it as an accepted answer to put closure to your question? Hannu's answer was published sooner and is a better candidate for acceptance.

Answer (score 4):

This is the expected and documented behaviour:

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the
          matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word
          constituent  character.   Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed
          by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters  are  letters,  digits,
          and the underscore.
```

If  you add a dash, it terminates your first word as a dash is a "non-word constituent character".  If you write the words together, then a word-regexp grep will treat it as one word and not match it.

What exactly it is that you want to do?

If you only want to know if your line is football01 and nothing else, you can do it as

```
grep -i "^football01$"
```

If you want to achieve something else, could you please explain what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The `-w` switch is for word regex. In file1, football01test is a word and in file2 football01 and test are two words separated by a hyphen.

man grep says this for `-w`

> Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
>   words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the
>   beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word  constituent 
>   character.   Similarly,  it  must  be either  at  the  end  of  the 
>   line or followed by a non-word constituent character. 
>   Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

Since `football01` doesn't match `football01test` as a whole word, you aren't getting that info from grep.

If you were to do `grep -i ^football01 file1.txt`, you will get both lines.